# Is there a better way to re-write below python code keeping the time complexity in mind with large lists?

Tags: python, time-complexity

I am trying to learn Python by coding as much as I can and came across this problem where I have a list of integers and a number, I should make it an incremental list by comparing to the previous element and adding the given  number to it if it's smaller or equal to its previous element and return the total times that I had to add the number to each of the element to make it an incremental list.

```
input = [1,3,1,2,1,7]                                
num = 3
count = 0

for i in range(1,len(input)):
    while input[i] <= input[i-1]:
        input[i] += num
        count +=1
print (count) # returns 5
print (input) # returns [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10]
```

I tried the above approach and it works fine but trying to learn O(n) concepts and to see if I can achieve this in a best-case scenario when the list is long with time-complexity in mind.

Thanks for reading and help.

Comment: Your implementation is already O(n) - it performs exactly one loop across the collection and performs only fixed-time operations during that loop with no nesting.

Comment: You can avoid the `while` loop by observing that the number of times it would execute is predictable from the difference divided by `num`.

Comment: @g.d.d.c how is the `while` inside `for` does not count as nested? And how is it fixed time?

Comment: @QuangHoang because the while loop doesn't operate against the entire list, it only compares two elements of the list.  It may loop, but it does not loop with respect to the length of the input list in any way.

Comment: @g.d.d.c still, that while loop is data dependent. It looks more like O(mn) than O(n). A clear improvement is as suggested by tripleee

Comment: You’re… looking for an expression that rounds a number up to the next equivalent of another modulo `num`?  This is just a discrete math problem.

Comment: Hi @mrb28830 is below given solution works for you?

Comment: @tripleee so what will be the time complexity for the combination of ```for and while```? will that be a O(n2)?

Comment: @AkashPagar That was already covered quite well in previous comments. I'd go with the *O(mn)* analysis provided by QuangHoang a few comments back, though in the rough, that's still equivalent to *O(n)* and of course, you could probably come up with a good numeric approximation of the value of *m* for a particular configuration if you needed a very detailed analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the `while` loop part which is taking more time in your code. You can try the following code which does not have `while` condition in for loop. Execution time for both the implementaions is given below for comparison.

```py
import itertools
import random
import time
####### this part is for generating list of random numbers has length 10000 ####### 
def random_gen(low, high):
    while True:
        yield random.randrange(low, high)

gen = random_gen(1, 100)
input = list(itertools.islice(gen, 10000))
##############################################################################
num = 3
count = 0

start = time.time() # start time for calculating time 

for i in range(1,len(input)):
    if input[i-1] < input[i]:
        continue
    elif input[i-1] == input[i]:
        input[i] = input[i]+num
        count+=1
    elif input[i-1] > input[i]:
        diff = input[i-1] - input[i]
        quotiont = (diff//num)+1
        input[i] += quotiont*num
        count+=quotiont

end = time.time() # end time after processing list

print(count)
print(input)
print(end-start)
```

Output: Execution time using this implementation on my machine is:

```
0.01267862319946289
```

Output Execution time using your code is:

```
13.800339698791504
```